# Does Azure Key Vault support KMIP?

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, kmip

I have an application I want to run in Azure that can use the KMIP protocol to communicate with key management servers.  Does Azure Key Vault support KMIP?  If so, were can I find the details?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Key Vault does not have a KMIP interface.

Azure Key Vault has a REST interface, based heavily on the JSON Web Key standard. It is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn903609.aspx

Sumedh